# Launch one Android App from another android App without using intents

Tags: android

Need to launch one android application (say Watsapp) from another android application (custom application) . I could achieve this using intent. My problem is : Once watsapp opens, it is not returning back to my custom app. Watsapp should run in background and control should return back to my custom app.

Comment: `Watsapp should run in background and control should return back to my custom app.` So why bother running Watsapp?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on rooted device, you can use command to kill process instead